# How to unset some elements of JSON Array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to unset some elements of JSON Array, so if **pname** value start with **XX** it should unset. Normal JSON String gives me this

```
$json = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $loc);

[{"uid":"352","pcode1":"AB1","pname":"XXAB1"},....}]
```

If I hardcode **pname** value like this

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) 
     {
        if (in_array('XXAB1', $value)) {
                unset($json[$key]);
            }
    }
    $j = json_encode($json);
    echo $j;
```

it works unsets that array but how can I do this dynamically ? So that each **pname** value begins with **XX** can be unsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match` like as

```
if(preg_match('/^[X]{2}/',$value['pname'])){
    unset($json[$key]);
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/456975)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried your suggestion instead of `in_array()` but not having much luck.

Comment: If I don't use `json_decode($json,true);` it works, very strange. final code that worked `$json = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $loc);  
  foreach ($json as $key => $value)
  {
   if(preg_match('/^[X]{2}/',$value['pname'])){
    unset($json[$key]);
   }
  }
  $j = json_encode($json);
  echo $j;` Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Within your foreach, you could use `strpos` to determine whether `XX` resides at the beginning of the string.

Using `===` strictly checks that `0` is returned and not `false`

```
<?php

$json = json_decode('[{"uid":"352","pcode1":"AB1","pname":"XXAB1"},{"uid":"352","pcode1":"AB1","pname":"XAB1"}]',true);

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($value['pname'], 'XX') === 0) {
        unset($json[$key]);
    }
}

$j = json_encode($json);
echo $j;

print_r($json);
```

https://3v4l.org/hZLDP